# Binary to Decimal Conversion doesn't work

Tags: c#, binary

This is kind of a funky program.  For some reason it works when the binary input is something like 101.  Then it doesn't for 1000.  This is kind of odd.  Could someone please explain?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {         
            string binary = "xxx";
            double decimalValue = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter in a binary number:");
            binary = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Length is: {0}", binary.Length);

                if (binary[i] == 49)  //Look at that
                    decimalValue = decimalValue + Math.Pow(2, i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The decimal equivalent value is {0}", decimalValue);

            Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The heart of it is of course 
    if (binary[i] == 49)

I'm just making it to teach myself some C#.  Could someone tell me what to put on the right side other than 49, which is the ASCII number for "1".  If I put "1" I get an error saying you can't compare a string to a char.

Any help would be appreciated.  I don't want to use the pre-canned convert to binary method, because this is supposed to be a teachable moment.

Comment: Hint: try `Math.Pow(2, binary.Length - i - 1)` ;)

Comment: A char literal is enclosed in single quotes: `'1'`.

Comment: If you can't compare a string to a char, why don't you try converting one to the other? You could also try parsing (hint) the string to an integer to see if it is a 1 or a 0.

Comment: The '1' works for 101, but not 1000.  It's better than that 49 cryptic value though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the characters from the wrong end.

As was said immediately in the first comment to the question, by Lucas Trzesniewski, replace one use of `i` (*not* both) inside the `for` loop with `binary.Length - 1 - i`.

The reason why it works for `"101"` is that this is a palindrome (reads the same backwards).

Note: `49` is the ASCII code for `'1'`. It is more readable to use `== '1'` than `== 49`. However, both work equally well. In C# you get a `char` value if you use single quotes, as in `'1'`, and you get a `string` object reference if you use double quotes, `"1"`.

You should remove the stuff with `"xxx"`. It has no function. Just do`string binary = Console.ReadLine();`.

Comment: Thanks.  I seriously didn't know that the zeroith character in a string is the left-most.  Now I know.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to add the value of each individual bit based on it's position you could take another approach: shift and add. In this approach you shift the current value to the left (by multiplying that value by 2) and adding the current bit.

For instance: the binary value `1010` becomes decimal 10 in four cycles:

```
value = 0
value *= 2 => value = 0
value += bit 1 => value = 1
value *= 2 => value = 2
value += bit 0 => value = 2
value *= 2 => value = 4
value += bit 1 => value = 5
value *= 2 => value = 10
value += bit 0 => value = 10
```

Or, in code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string binary = "";
        double decimalValue = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter in a binary number:");
        binary = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i++)
        {
            decimalValue *=2; // shift current value to the left
            if (binary[i] == 49)
            {
                decimalValue += 1; // add current bit
            }   
            Console.WriteLine("Current value: {0}", decimalValue);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The decimal equivalent value is {0}", decimalValue);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: You could also use the `long` type instead of `double`, in which case you could write the [*fancy* `<<=` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayt2kcfb.aspx): `decimalValue <<= 1;` instead of `decimalValue *= 2;` :-)